# Trying to run python script on pressing a html button

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to run a python script on pressing an HTML button. The script takes in a command-line argument and then prints the results based on the entered sentence. I am not sure why it is not working. The script that I want to run on entering text and pressing the HTML button is called WebOutputTest.py. I am not sure why nothing is happening when I enter the text and press the button. When I press the button its not even taking me to the website followed by the path which would be /external.

code snippet from index.html

```
<form action="/external/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   Input Text:
   <input type="text" name="param" required> <br><br>
   {{data_external}}<br><br>
   {{data}}
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Check tweet">

   </form>
```

code snippet from views.py

```
def external(request):
  inp = request.POST.get('param')
  out= run([sys.executable,'//Users//yaminhimani//Desktop//tweetybird//WebOutputTest.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
  print(out)
  return render(request,'index.html',{'data': out.stdout})
```

code snippet from urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.noreq), #shows the html template for the website 
    path('external',views.external),
]
```

this is the python file I want to run after entering the text in the box and pressing the html button

```
db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()
txt = WebOutput.WebOutput(sys.argv[1])


db.match_tweet_for_website(txt)
```